# Неправильный sql запрос (SQL C#)

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

Всем привет! Опишу суть проблемы есть некая база данных (таблица книг) и надо сделать поиск по определенному параметру даной таблицы....делаю к примеру запрос поиска по имени автора:

```
    SqlConnection MyBaseConnector;
        MyBaseConnector = new SqlConnection(MyAdress);
        MyBaseConnector.Open();
              SqlCommand MyFindComand = null;

                string MyParam = "";
                MyParam = "'" + MyFindParam + "'"; //FindParam - значение получаемое из TextBox (Пользователь сам вводит значение по которому проводится поиск)
                if (NameFinder == true)
                {
                   MyFindComand = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name,Author,Year,Number,Tags,Count,ForBorrow,PdfAvailable FROM [Books] WHERE Author=" + MyParam, MyBaseConnector);

                }

                SqlDataReader TableReader = null;
                try
                    {
                    TableReader =  MyFindComand.ExecuteReader();

                    while(TableReader.Read())
                    {

   }       
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (TableReader != null)
                        {
                            TableReader.Close();
                        }
                    }
```

В данном коде в цикле while TableReader.Read() всегда будет возвращать false, хотя когда сам запрос будет выглядеть например вот так:

```
  MyFindComand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Books]", MyBaseConnector);
```

то все будет работать корректно....видимо проблема в самом запросе, но вот я не пойму что не так.Может быть сможете подсказать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все столбцы должны быть в квадратных скобках.
`MyFindComand = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Name],[Author],[Year],[Number],[Tags],[Count],[ForBorrow],[PdfAvailable] FROM [Books] WHERE Author=" + MyParam, MyBaseConnector);`

Comment: Я так понимаю ты работаешь в Visual Studio, так вот там есть встроенный интерфейс для всего этого дела, когда нажимаешь "показать таблицу данных", в высветившемся интерфейсе нажми на фильтр сверху возле кнопки обновить и так складай запросы.

Comment: Ты не представляешь себе как я тебе благодарен чувак!Большое спасибо!